# IMAP: (JavaMail) Get unread message count of many folders (performance improvement)

Tags: java, directory, jakarta-mail, imap, message

Our client has an imap mail account of 400 folders. We fetch mails using java mail api. On the start of the program we need all the **unread message count** of each folder.

Suppose we have the foldernames in a string array

```
String arryFolderNames[] = { "f1", "f2"..
```

And for each folder:

```
for (String folderName : arryFolderNames) {
    IMAPFolder imapFolder = MailStore.getFolder(folderName);

    //takes 100-300 milliseconds
    int unreadCount = imapFolder.getUnreadMessageCount();
}
```

To get the unread message count of a single folder takes at least 100 milliseconds and totally the whole process takes more than 40 seconds, but the customer demands only 5-6 sec. at most. I have to optimize this process:

- All folders are closed and I perform *getUnreadMessgeCount* on a closed folder. But when I check before call of getUnreadCount whether folder is opened and open the folder, getUnreadCount and close again, then folder open/close process takes additional time and I do not get any performance gain.
- When I open all 400 folder at once, and keep them open, everything becomes slower and as think it is not a good practice to have all folders opened always.
- When I put the folder.getUnreadCount in different Threads, (Thread blocks with 10 size, or 1 thread for a folder, with 400 threads, or 4 threads with 100 folders, etc.) there is no gain and processing all folders takes longer time.

Any suggestions, ideas?

Comment: What does your client demand 5-6 seconds for? The complete result? Can it be that they just want to see *any* result as quick as possible? In this case you can try to poll those folders and display results asynchronously. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Are you using the current version of JavaMail?  List your session properties and start bench-marking with different [IMAP session properties settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html).

Comment: Yes we use the latest API. What type of session property can improve that, most of the properties are login/ssl based and fetching attachments related.

Comment: @benchpresser Read the text in the right most column.  There are parameters for pool sizes, store connection reuse, compression, buffers/fetch sizes, and DNS look-ups.  Some of those defaults may not be what you want.

Comment: Assuming the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) shows that you're making all the requests using a single connection, and not creating a new connection for each request, you may just be limited by the speed of the server.  You could try using multiple Stores to the same server and connecting multiple times to get multiple connections and then split the requests across the connections in parallel.

Comment: @Bill Shannon Thank you for informations, they are very usefull. Another question, what about keeping the folders opened in a single store? Suppose we have 400 folders, in my implementaion I open the needed folder one then close it, but open/close takes some time. I have also to check whether folder is opend for example if we call getMessagesByUid. But AFAIK, keeping all folders always OPENED is not a good practice, after some number of opened folders, the mail server becomes slower to response.

Comment: Is it a goog idea using a StorePool within one Session and use the stores on demand? I see that  there is a performance gain if we have 10 threads each one has its own store for example. Can mailserver blame me for too many connections? I think I should find a configurable limit of maximum stores for different providers.

Comment: The answer to most of your questions is "it depends on your mail server".  In general, you should only keep folders open if they're being *actively* used.  In any event, the server may close your connection at any time so you'll need to plan for that.  The JavaMail imap provider can maintain a connection pool to use when opening folders; see the [`mail.imap.connectionpoolsize`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.connectionpoolsize) property.

Comment: Is correct? To gain performance I use a single SESSION, use 10 different threads, each Thread has its own STORE, each store has its own connection and i divide for example 200 folders in these 10 connections, each store has 20 folders to process, but when finished processing i should close the folders and also the store connections. So I should not keep these 10 connections always live and keep the number of opened folders minimum. What about to the folder references, should they be kept, or called newly each time Store.getFolder(..) for example if we operare on INBOX often?